# Bottom overflowed by 100.0 pxl

Tags: flutter

I have this UI :[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEEwK.jpg)

And the text is showing this yellow bar, even when I set the maxlines to 3..
I put them in a container and its still like this!

```
child: Container(
                                  height: 150,
                                  width: 200,
                                  child: Column(children: [
                                    Text(
                                      allRecipes[index].name,
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54,
                                      fontSize: 20,),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      allRecipes[index].about,
                                      softWrap: true,
                                      maxLines: 3,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 14,)
                                    ),
```

**Also, I need help from you so I can make more space between the food cards??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because your Container Height.
try to increase this and check,

your Container height is 150
increase this 200 or 250. as per your design requirement.

```
                          Container(
                                  height: 250,//like this
                                  width: 200,
                                  child: Column(children: [
                                    Text(
                                      allRecipes[index].name,
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54,
                                      fontSize: 20,),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      allRecipes[index].about,
                                      softWrap: true,
                                      maxLines: 3,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 14,)
                                    ),
                                  ]
                                 )
```

Comment: Can you help me with the spaces between cards?

Comment: can you define "spaces".means where you need this

Comment: Sorry but what is "spaces".means ?

Comment: i am asking for this "Can you help me with the spaces between cards?" where you need this, between images and text or between two text.

Comment: Oh sorry, it is my fault. I need the spaces between two cards, not inside the card itself